# How to get ListItemCollection.Files paginated results

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-foundation, csom, mvc

I have the following method in place and trying figure out how to update for paginated results using int pageSize & int page parameters. Currently I have pageSize working using CamlQuery RowLimit, but not sure how to use page as there does not appear to be any built in methods:

```
public static List<SharePointCustomDocumentObj> GetDocumentsByFolderPath(string siteUrl, string folderPath, bool includeAllSubFolders = true, int pageSize = 10, int page = 1)
{
    List<SharePointCustomDocumentObj> docs = new List<SharePointCustomDocumentObj>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(siteUrl) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderPath))
    {
        try
        {
             
            // get site auth client context (gets disposded end of using statement)
            using (ClientContext spClientContext = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, _clientId, _clientSecret))
            {
                if (spClientContext != null)
                {
                    // include sub-folders optional query scope
                    HtmlString recursiveAllAttribute = includeAllSubFolders ? new HtmlString("Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"") : new HtmlString(string.Empty);

                    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery(); // init new caml query

                    camlQuery.DatesInUtc = false; // uses site regional time zone datetime when set to false

                    // caml query filter by folder path - format: {sites/sitename}/Shared Documents/{folderPath}
                    camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = GetSiteUrlAbsolutePath(siteUrl) + "/Shared Documents/" + folderPath;

                    // caml query files only, recursive, pagination statements
                    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View " + recursiveAllAttribute + ">" +
                                            "<Query>" +
                                                "<Where>" +
                                                    "<Eq><FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /><Value Type='Integer'>0</Value></Eq>" +
                                                "</Where>" +
                                            "</Query>" +
                                            "<RowLimit Paged=\"TRUE\">" + pageSize.ToString() + "</RowLimit>" +
                                        "</View>";

                    
                    List list = spClientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents"); // get root lists

                    ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery); // apply caml query to root lists

                    // load ListItem obj proprties
                    spClientContext.Load(listItems,
                            items => items.Include(
                                item => item.DisplayName,
                                item => item.FileSystemObjectType,
                                item => item.File,
                                item => item.File.UniqueId,
                                item => item.File.Name));

                    spClientContext.ExecuteQuery(); // execute query

                    if (listItems != null && listItems.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
                        {
                            // do stuff
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log (error) exception
        }
    }

    return docs;
}
```

In my view I would to call the method in following fashion (where pageSize and page would be passed via query strings on the page):

```
List<SharePointCustomDocumentObj> paginatedFiles = SharePointDocumentManager.GetDocumentsByFolderPath(spSiteUrl, "FolderPathName", true, 10, 1);
```

Return: Files 1-10

```
List<SharePointCustomDocumentObj> paginatedFiles = SharePointDocumentManager.GetDocumentsByFolderPath(spSiteUrl, "FolderPathName", true, 10, 2);
```

Return: Files 11-20

```
List<SharePointCustomDocumentObj> paginatedFiles = SharePointDocumentManager.GetDocumentsByFolderPath(spSiteUrl, "FolderPathName", true, 10, 3);
```

Return: Files 21-30

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Theres a `SP.ListItemCollectionPagination` class you can utilize, but it has it's limitations.

```
camlQuery.set_listItemCollectionPosition(position); 
var position = new SP.ListItemCollectionPosition(); 

position.set_pagingInfo(pageInfo);
```

where `pageinfo` can be derived from `PagePrev=True&Paged=TRUE&p_ID=<firstrowItemID>` or `Paged=TRUE&p_ID=<lastrowItemID>`

More info: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18606.sharepoint-2013-paging-with-sharepoint-client-object-model.aspx